# How do you add the top image in the Apple Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I recently noticed that some apps in the apple store have large image with the logo on their download page. I was just curious on how to do this and would like to implement it with my own apps.

Ex: Tinder & Bumble

[image: Click here to view image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add it.

This is possible only if your app is selected by the Apple editorial team to be featured

Comment: If you are ever featured, here is Apple's guidelines on those featured images.  App Store Promotional Artwork Guidelines: https://help.apple.com/itc/appspromoart/en.lproj/static.html